# Water droplets do not reflect the surface

Tags: particles, reflection

Drops of water are applied to this apple, which are themselves transparent (you can see through). The problem is that the drops do not reflect the surface of the apple and thus behave like a separate sight.

[image]

Properties / settings

- Transition = 1, roughness = 0
- Screen Sapace Refraction (material and rendering properties)
- radiation calculation
  are activated.

Does anyone have any idea why the drops don't reflect the surface?

Comment: Can you post a picture of it in rendered mode instead of material preview?

Comment: In the Material panel, under Settings, have you chosen Blend Mode > Alpha Blend?

Answer (score 0):

You are in material preview mode.
[image: modes]
Material preview mode uses the EEVEE render engine, but disables shadows for quick, viewport rendering. EEVEE fakes refraction using the world background.

To achieve realistic refraction in your final render, you can either use more expensive faking via screen space refraction (a 2D effect for EEVEE that can be enabled in render properties), or use the Cycles render engine instead. Note that your choice of render engine between these two **will not alter the material preview view from using downsized EEVEE rendering.** Refraction will always be faked there.

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug! In this mode (shading), Screen Space Refraction of the apple must not be enabled in the material settings. It only has to be enabled in the material properties of the water droplets.

[image]